# Post closed arbitrarily

Tags: support, reopen-closed

There was a post on [Kids PC or Mac games](https://superuser.com/questions/8100/games-for-kids-closed) that on SuperUser that has been closed because it was "not computer related". Can someone please correct this! Last time I checked PCs and Macs were both types of computer.

Comment: I rolled back the edit because I wasn't looking for an explanation of why it was closed as a reason was already given. The reason was a fallacy.

Comment: What I was really looking for was either for the post to be re-opened, or for the correct reason to be given on the post itself. Otherwise it looks like the person who closed it is being arbitrary and unreasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I closed the post and I followed Jeff Atwood's precedent of using the "Not Computer Related" Option (we have a limited number of options to choose from and this is the best fit).

Questions that are just asking about games are most likely not going to be allowed going further on SuperUser.

Comment: Perhaps a new closed reason is needed. It did look unreasonable given the OP said "PC or Mac" and that SU has been said to be for "anything computer related"

Comment: Colin: I have no problem with there being an extra close reason added (it would make things less confusing definitely). You could make the argument that just because someone said PC or Mac that still makes them much more games related than computing related. Although the games topics looked to be very popular, a lot of users were also complaining it runs the risk of turning SU into a games site instead of site where you get actual computing questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

With all the games stuff, SU is blocked by firewalls from several companies. I think they try to reduce these questions.

Comment: Fair reason - Then perhaps there should be a closure type of "closed because it was entertainment related". It is a pity that companies have to be idiots like that, as otherwise it was, I though, a reasonable question.